# History -- Analog IC Family Trees -- Any references showing evolution?

Tags: analog, history

Take an ancient and honorable IC, say the 741 opamp, or the 555 timer, or the 193 comparator.  My historical memory is faulty, but I believe they were the first of their kind.

Designs are always improving, and "next generation" replacements arrived like the LM321, then the LT1013, etc.

I'm looking for something like, "and designers saw they could solve the *xxx* phase reversal problem, and so they created the *yyy*, and that they could provide a single supply version so they the created *zzz*...".

Or, "upon seeing Vendor *aaa*'s part *xxx*, vendor *bbb* put out their own tweaked version, calling it *yyy*."

It should cover multiple vendors (lump the "me too"s together), and extra points for a "family tree" type diagram.  Even highlights of history with a couple dozen parts would be wonderful.

Comment: Probably not. The development was not simple. For instance, the 741 became popular because it did not need compensation, not because it was all that great. It largely replaced the 709, but there were all sorts of 700-series (from Fairchild, and there were other manufacturers with other families) which were faster, or had better leakage, etc.

Comment: I never got around to read the site myself and I think it is mostly transistor focussed, but it might be of some value to you: https://sites.google.com/site/transistorhistory/

Comment: Dave Jones [introduced](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oon6TyiUx9Q) a documentary task by Karl Von Mollers, [State of Electronics](http://www.stateofelectronics.com/). I've got a hunch it might include some information of interest to you.

Comment: and the 709 begat the 741

Answer (score 6):

Some Opamp history I've collected:

If you start with ICs, the first opamp was probably the 702, and the improved version 709 (1st generation) was the first widely used version.  Bob Widlar did it again with the LMx01 to start the 2nd generation.  The ua741 is a 101 with onboard compensation cap.

Single supply LM324 and dual 358 started another generation.  Superbeta LM102 and 110, then the MC1556 started another major branch of the tree.  The LM108 started a long line of precision low input current devices.

OP08/OP108 added thermal balancing, and the LT1008 and LT1012 introduced input bias current cancellation.  The OP97/
OP297/OP497 were marketed as tight specs with low power.  The AD517 was the first laser trimmed opamp I know of.

Another branch is the ua725 then OP05 and OP07 which exploited the thermal symmetry axis and zener zapping to become the standard device of its precision class.  OP27/OP37, with lower noise and increased speed, is another class standard.

An early (first?) FET opamp with JFET inputs is AD503/506, followed by the µA740, and Intersil ICL8007.  Ion implantation in FET devices brough forth LF155/LF156/LF157, the OP15/16/17, and the CA3130/3140.  The TL06/07/08 became standard devices, and the line reached its highest precision with the AD547.  AD711/AD712, AD548/AD648, and OP249 markedly lowered the price for good performance.

Very low noise (electrometer) started with the OP111 with a dielectrically-isolated process for fabrication and P channel JFETs in the first 2 stages addressing LF155/156/157 deficiencies. AD549, AD546, and AD795 followed.
AD743/745 are low voltage and current noise rivaling BJTs.

The LM118/218/318, AD518 and AD744 addressed speed limits from PNP transistors culminating in the AD84x series and the AD811 added current feedback.

And the above is all pre-2000.  I'll gladly correct/amend/update.